# Tableau replacing backward slash by slash in UNC path

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to create a Tableau's workbook connected to a CSV file. This file is on another server, in a shared folder. I can access it on Tableau Desktop, but when I publish it on Tableau Server, it doesn't work. My workbook doesn't find my file.

I unchecked Include External File and my shared folder is shared to everyone, so I don't understand why it doesn't work.

My only hint is that I specify my path like

```
"\\servername\folder\...\"
```

and Tableau diplay :

```
"The directory is missing or has been moved: //servername/folder/...".
```

Have you already seen that issue ? Have you any solutions ?

> Note : my file is on a Windows server and Tableau on a Linux one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to mount the network shares to a mount point on your Linux Tableau server, then tell Tableau where to find the mount points and their associated UNC path. See [this article](https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-11259) by Tableau on how to do this.

In short, Windows lets us connect to different disk drives or servers/computers using the `C:\ D:\ A:\ \\servername` notation. On Linux, every drive and network share is given a "mount point", such as `/mnt/flashdrive` or `/mnt/servername`, and you have to explicitly tell it what type of connection it is whereas Windows can try to figure it out for you.